# name error uninitialized constant path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a form that will post to a database, I'm really struggling at the moment and i'm getting this error.

```
NameError in AddController#index
uninitialized constant AddController::Newevents
```

Could you advise what i would need to do?

Heres all the code i have

Form

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@newevent) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :eventname, required: true %>
<%= f.input :eventdate %>
<%= f.input :eventimage %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
class AddController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @newevent = Newevent.new
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Newevent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def event_params
      params.require(:Newevent).permit(:eventname, :eventdate, :eventimage)
    end
end
```

Routes

```
  resources :add
```

**Edit**

i now have this error `undefined method`newevents_path'` after changing this

```
@newevents = Newevent.new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you miscopied your code here. The error message indicates that your index method actually looks like this

```
def index
    @newevent = Newevents.new
end
```

Remove the `s` from the end of `Newevent` and it should work.

RE: your edit

Your routes declare that you have a resource named `add`, if you want to show and create your `Newevent` objects, then you should create a controller for that. Declare `resources :newevents` in your routes and create a controller to handle it.

You should research RESTful routes, because that's what Rails's `resource` routing works best with. The form to create a new object should be displayed by the `new` action and not `index`.

Comment: if i remove the s, from it i get this error, `undefined method `newevents_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd138342068>:0x007fd1383415f0>`

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `create` method instead of `index` if you are using POST http method. `index` will be called if you are using GET method and it shouldn't be used to post the form data. Refer this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information on rails routing.

```
class AddController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @newevent = Newevent.new
  end
end
```